# need sum of value in array of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sum values from an array. I have an array of arrays.

```
let exampleArray =[[[['1','2'],'3'],'4'],'5'];
```

I need the sum of all the values using `reducer` or `map`

Comment: why do you have strings? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You first have to flatten array and then you can use `reduce`to get sum as:

```js
let exampleArray = [[[['1', '2'], '3'], '4'], '5'];

const result = exampleArray
    .flat(Infinity)
    .reduce((acc, curr) => +curr + acc, 0);
console.log(result);
```

You can also use recursion here as:

```js
let exampleArray = [[[['1', '2'], '3'], '4'], '5'];

function getTotal(arr) {
    return !Array.isArray(arr[0])
            ? +arr[0] + +arr[1]
            : getTotal(arr[0]) + +arr[1];
}

getTotal(exampleArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const red = array => {
  return array.reduce((sum, current) => {
    if (Array.isArray(current)) {
      return sum + red(current)
    }
    return sum + +current
  }, 0)
}
red([[['1','2'],'3'],'4'],'5'])
```